# Form submission, validate and open link in new tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I have a form on lets say http://www.domain1.com which uses jquery validate and on successful validation I want it to submit the form to upsales.com (a crm system) I use (but I have no control over the code on upsales.com) and to also open a link in a new tab - lets say to: http://www.domain1.com/file.pdf, aswell as submit the form, this is what I have tried:

```
jQuery('.propertyDetailForm').validate({
    rules: {
        'Client.name': {
            required: true,
        },
        'Contact.email': {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'Contact.phone': {
            minlength: 9,
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery('#submitForm').click(); 
        jQuery('.propertyDetailForm').submit();
    }
});
```

this is the link I need to click on successful validation: jQuery('#submitForm').click();

but at the moment its only submitting the form and not emulating a click.

I have also tried of the submitHandler:

```
jQuery('.propertyDetailForm').validate({
    rules: {
        'Client.name': {
            required: true,
        },
        'Contact.email': {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'Contact.phone': {
            minlength: 9,
            required: true
        }
    }
});       

if (jQuery(".propertyDetailForm").validate().form()) {
    jQuery('#submitForm').click(); 
    jQuery('.propertyDetailForm').submit();
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<form id="upsales_form" class="main-prop form inline upsale-form propertyDetailForm" method="POST" action="https://power.upsales.com/api/external/formSubmit" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="Client.name" class="control-label">Name*:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Name*:" id="ClientName" name="Contact.name" class="form-control required">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="Contact.email" class="control-label">Email*:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Email*:" name="Contact.email" class="form-control required email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="Contact.phone" class="control-label">Phone*:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" required="" placeholder="eg. 952123456" id="Contact.phone" name="Contact.phone" class="form-control required input-small">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="check-group" class="control-group chkbox-container">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="Client.custom_47" name="Client.custom_47" class="form-control">
            Please tick if you require a mortgage
            <img width="30" src="assets/media/images/logo_dnb_100.jpg">
        </label>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div id="buttonWrapper">
                <a target="_blank" id="submitForm" href="http://www.domain.com/file.pdf" style="display: none;"></a>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="upsalesSubmit" type="submit">Download Property PDF NOW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not make any sense.  You're trying to redirect the browser at nearly the same instance you're opening a tab?  The `.submit()` is going to submit the form and redirect the browser to the URL in the form's `action` attribute.  You cannot open a tab when you're going to a new page; and if the tab is on the new page, then you cannot open it before you get there.  Client-side JavaScript can only control the currently loaded page, not others before they're loaded. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your code that's going to run when the valid form is submitted...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    jQuery('#submitForm').click(); 
    jQuery('.propertyDetailForm').submit();
}
```

Your `.submit()` is going to submit the form and redirect the browser to load the URL in the form's `action` attribute...

```
action="https://power.upsales.com/api/external/formSubmit"
```

If the tab is on the new page, then you cannot open it *before* you get there.  Client-side JavaScript can only control the currently loaded page, not others before they're loaded.

You have not shown your code for the tabs, but typically, jQuery tab plugins allow you to load the page with a tab already open by using an anchor.  Something like this...

```
action="https://power.upsales.com/api/external/formSubmit/#Tab3"
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought, unfortunately I don't have access to the content on upsales.com as its a CRM so I can't locate something that is or isn't there, I only have access to the content of the HTML on the site where the form is, is there another way I can perhaps achieve my outcome? in this case to download the file and to submit the form's contents.

Comment: @user1338176,  download what file?  And I have no idea what upsales.com has to do with anything... I just thought that was your website.  If that's not even your site, then you absolutely cannot control it with JavaScript.  I think you should edit your OP to clarify any critical missing details.